# Authentication program

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I have 2 interfaces: login and register.

I have an error in saving the username and password data into a text file.

And i have a problem in reading back the data to proceed with the authentication.

This my code:

```
import Tkinter 
WindowBox = Tkinter.Tk()
WindowBox.geometry("250x200")
WindowBox.title("Welcome to E-UPSR")

getusername = Tkinter.StringVar()
getpassword = Tkinter.StringVar()

LabelName = Tkinter.Label (WindowBox, text="Username:")
LabelName.pack()
TxtBoxName = Tkinter.Entry (WindowBox, textvariable= getusername)
TxtBoxName.pack()

LabelName = Tkinter.Label (WindowBox, text="Password:")
LabelName.pack()
TxtBoxName = Tkinter.Entry (WindowBox, textvariable= getpassword)
TxtBoxName.pack()

tudent=[]

def read():
    addstudent = open ("student.txt", "w")
    addstudent.write("User ID: " + entry_box1.get())
    addstudent.write("\nUser Password: " + entry_box2.get())
    addstudent.close ()

def back():
    RegBox.withdraw()
    WindowBox.deiconify()
    return    

def register():
    WindowBox.withdraw()
    RegBox.deiconify()
    return

RegBox = Tkinter.Tk()
RegBox.geometry("250x200")
RegBox.title("register")

LabelName = Tkinter.Label (RegBox, text="Enter Username:")
LabelName.pack()
TxtBoxName = Tkinter.Entry (RegBox, textvariable= getusername)
TxtBoxName.pack()

LabelName = Tkinter.Label (RegBox, text="Enter Password:")
LabelName.pack()
TxtBoxName = Tkinter.Entry (RegBox, textvariable= getpassword)
TxtBoxName.pack()
RegBox.withdraw()

def save():
    getusername=entry_box1.get()
    getpassword=entry_box2.get()
    addstudent = open ("student.txt", "w")
    addstudent.write("Username:" + entry_box1.get())
    addstudent.write("Password: " + entry_box2.get())
    addstudent.close ()

BtnName = Tkinter.Button (RegBox, text="Back", command=back).pack()   
BtnName = Tkinter.Button (RegBox, text="Enter", command=save).pack()
BtnName = Tkinter.Button (WindowBox, text="Register", command=register).pack()
BtnName = Tkinter.Button (WindowBox, text="Proceed", command=read).pack()

WindowBox.mainloop()
```

Comment: You never defined `entry_box1` or `entry_box2` but you're trying to call `get()` on them.

Comment: Could you please post what error messages are you getting? Thanks.

Comment: can you give me example?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited the question to be answerable.

Comment: You are creating two root windows. Tkinter isn't designed to work that way. If you need more than one window, create instances of `Toplevel`.

Comment: Feel free to accept someone's answer or vote up.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't create `entry_box1` and `entry_box2` in code but you try to use it in `entry_box1.get()` and `entry_box2.get()`

You have to use `getusername` instead of `entry_box1` and `getpassword` instead of `entry_box2` in two places

```
addstudent.write("Username:" + getusername.get())
addstudent.write("Password: " + getpassword.get())
```

and

```
addstudent.write("User ID: " + getusername.get())
addstudent.write("\nUser Password: " + getpassword.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

As `Jkdc` said `entry_box1` or `entry_box2` are not defined but you have created `getusername` and `getpassword` variables for `password` and `username` so use `getusername.get()` to get username and `getpassword.get()`
to get password.

```
def read():
    addstudent = open ("student.txt", "w")
    addstudent.write("User ID: " + getusername.get())
    addstudent.write("\nUser Password: " + getpassword.get())
    addstudent.close ()
```

...

```
def save():
    getusername=entry_box1.get()
    getpassword=entry_box2.get()
    addstudent = open ("student.txt", "w")
    addstudent.write("Username:" + getusername.get())
    addstudent.write("Password: " + getpassword.get())
    addstudent.close ()
```

Comment: thnx a lot guys. i appreciate it

Comment: @newbie Feel free to accept this answer for the community.

Answer (score 0):

Lines 41 & 46:

```
TxtBoxName = Tkinter.Entry (RegBox, textvariable= getusername)

TxtBoxName = Tkinter.Entry (RegBox, textvariable= getpassword)
```

These need to be assigned as variables, in your code, they share the same variable name (or should i say that 'TxtBoxName' value is overwritten each time you declare a new element with the name 'TxtBoxName. The reason they still appear is because you have already packed their values into the widget).

When you call `Entry.get()` on lines 56 & 57:

```
addstudent.write("Username:" + entry_box1.get())

addstudent.write("Password: " + entry_box2.get())
```

Your calling the get method on variable names that don't exist. `TxtBoxName.get()` however will work, look again at the paragraph above and you should see why that will not give you the desired effect.

If you sort out your variable issues and your code will run fine (As i have made it do so). It is important to understand why this has happened, as this is simple python.

When you have fixed your code, don't be alarmed if your windows stay when registration is complete, you will need to add another method call to destroy the window.